# remove border from swt tree

Tags: java, tree, swt

I need to remove border what is on that screen.

[image]

I am trying to use style SWT.NONE but with no effect ;/

I create tree using managedForm

```
final Tree tree = mForm.getToolkit().createTree(parent, SWT.NONE);
```

Comment: I don't see any border in my code when I use `SWT.NONE`: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/iIXzIgy.png). Maybe the `Composite` it's contained in has a border?

Comment: @ John Smith: Can you show some code? SWT.NONE is working for me for both Tree and TreeViewer.

Comment: Please always include a minimal working example, like an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: The toolkit will be adding the border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try:

```
FormToolkit toolkit = mForm.getToolkit();
toolkit.setBorderStyle(SWT.NULL);
final Tree tree = toolkit.createTree(parent, SWT.NONE);
```